# Adding QRcode reading functionality to a native iPhone app

Tags: iphone, qr-code

Can anyone point me in the right direction for information or tutorials for adding a QRcode reader to a native iPhone app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ZBar iPhone SDK

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html

Answer (score 0):

ZXing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and ZBar (above) are the ones heard about most. ZBar is LGPL 2.1, ZXing is Apache 2.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README describes integrating the provided widget into an Xcode project.